# How to extract an element from a deque?

Tags: c++, stl, deque

Given the following code :

```
void World::extractStates(deque<string> myDeque)
{
    unsigned int i = 0;
    string current; // current extracted string

    while (i < myDeque.size())      // run on the entire vector and extract all the elements
    {
        current =  myDeque.pop_front(); // doesn't work 
        // do more stuff
    }
}
```

I want to extract each iteration the element at the front , but `pop_front()` is a `void` 
method . How can I get the element (at the front) then ?

Regards

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque/front

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use [`front`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/deque/deque/front/) to read the item and `pop_front` to remove it.

```
current = myDeque.front();
myDeque.pop_front();
```

This way of doing things may seem counter-productive, but it is necessary in order for `deque` to provide adequate [exception-safety guarantees](http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/082.htm).